# Kotlin: 'if' must have both main and 'else' branches if used as an expression

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to run this code:

```
fun main() {
    print("This is a calculator")
    print("enter your first number")
    val no1 = readLine()!!
    print("enter your operation")
    val operation1 = readLine()!!
    print("enter your second number")
    val no2 = readLine()!!

    val result = if(operation1 == '*')
    print("$val no1 * $val no2")
}
```

But I get the following error:

> 'if' must have both main and 'else' branches if used as an expression
> Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'String' and 'Char' Keyword cannot
> be used as a reference Keyword cannot be used as a reference

It also keeps coming up with Kotlin: Keyword cannot be used as a reference within my IDE.

I am very new to Kotlin and I am just trying to create a basic calculator, can you please help?

Comment: `print("$no1 * $no2")`. Also, not sure why are you assigning the output of `if` to a variable. `print` will always return `Unit`. and in this case `if` requires `else`

Comment: and `no1` and `no2` would be strings, if you want to print the multiplication, you first need to convert these variables to `Int` and and multiply,

Comment: `$val` is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code has three different compilation errors, and many other things to fix:

- In the line:
  `print("$val no1 * $val no2")`
  the `$val` is a string template which would fill in the value of the variable `val` — but `val` isn't a variable; it's a keyword. (That's what's causing the ‘Keyword cannot be used as a reference’ error.) I think you want `$no1` and `$no2`.
- The test `if(operation1 == '*')` is comparing a string with a character. (Single-quotes give a character constant. A string *contains* characters, but it *is* not a character, so it can never be equal to a character.) The compiler tells you this with the error ‘Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'String' and 'Char'’. The simplest way to fix it is to provide a string by using double-quotes instead: `"*"`.
- The pair of lines:
  `val result = if(operation1 == '*')`
  `print("$val no1 * $val no2")`
  is incomplete and doesn't make sense as it is. What do you want to do if `operation1` *isn't* "*"? And what do you want to set `result` to in each case?
  (It looks like you're trying to use `if` as an expression, and assign its result to `result` — but to use `if` as an expression you need to add an `else` branch too, so it knows what value to use in all cases. That's causing the compilation error ‘'if' must have both main and 'else' branches if used as an expression’.)
- If this is the start of some code which will check for `*`, `+`, and other operators, then maybe you want to set the result and *then* print it, e.g.:
  `val result = if (operation1 == "*") /* … */`
               `else if (operation2 == "+") /* … */`
               `else /* … */`
  `print(result)`
  (Though that would be simpler with [`when`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression) instead of `if`.)
- If you fix the first issue by changing it to "$no1 * $no2", that will print e.g. `1 * 2`. I'm guessing you want instead to *calculate* the product of two numbers. But `no1` and `no2` aren't numbers; they're strings. So you first have to convert them into numbers, e.g. with `no1.toInt()`. You also have to tell the compiler that you want to *evaluate* the `*` rather than just printing it. If you just want to print out the number, you could skip the string template entirely:
  `print(no1.toInt() * no2.toInt())`
  However, if you want to use a [string template](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-syntax.html#string-templates) (e.g. if you want to add some text), you'd have to use the `${…}` format to mark out the bit you want to evaluate:
  `print("${no1.toInt() * no2.toInt()}")`
- Some or all of the `print(…)` calls should probably be `println(…)`. (`println()` adds a line-break after the string, while `print()` doesn't, leaving the next input or output to follow immediately on the same line.)
- Even if all that's fixed, the code could fail in several ways if the user doesn't enter the expected input. (Both `!!` and `toInt()` can throw exceptions, e.g. if you press Enter without typing a number.) That's fine for an exercise, of course; but if this code ever got to production, you'd want to handle those possibilities better.

Comment: That works, thank you but now I have a new problem, decimal places dont exist, it just rounds

Comment: Yes, [`toInt()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-int.html) converts a string to, well, an integer! If you want to convert to a float or a double instead, then use [`toFloat()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-float.html) or [`toDouble()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-double.html).

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$val`, it is trying to access the `val` variable, but as `$val` is undefined, it can't, and freaks out because it doesn't know what to do.

Instead of `print("$val no1 * $val no2")`, you can use:

```
print("$no1 * $no2")
```

The code above will use the `$no1` and `$no2` variables that you want it to use.

Answer (score 0):

In line 4 and 8, the input should be converted to `Int`, like this:

```kotlin
val no1 = readLine()!!.toInt()
val no2 = readLine()!!.toInt()
```

In the last line, `val` should not be written and should be as follows:

```kotlin
print("$no1 * $no2")
```

You can also add other operators using `else if` in the continuation of the `if` command